# Lightweight C++ Gui Library

Tags: c++, user-interface, frameworks

I want to create GUI applications with C++ on Windows. I have downloaded Qt, and it works well, but it has so much stuff in it and so many header files that I really don't use. It is a nice framework, but it has more than just GUI.

Are there any lighter GUI libraries out there for Windows C++ that is "just GUI"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

FLTK, if you are serious about lightweight.

http://www.fltk.org/

edit:
Blurb from the website:

FLTK is designed to be small and modular enough to be statically linked, but works fine as a shared library. FLTK also includes an excellent UI builder called FLUID that can be used to create applications in minutes.

I'll add that its *mature* and *stable*, too.

Comment: It's really good, but also a little ugly. Is there anything like that with *native* L&F?

Comment: Nothing I know of that's lightweight. wxWidgets wraps the native widgets (mostly - where possible) while remaining cross platform. It's definitely a larger, heavier platform though.

Comment: https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear. okay this one was not here. :)

Comment: note: fltk is flexible enough not to be ugly, you just have to work at it.

Comment: And if you want good looks with lightweight, use the new NanoGUI

Answer (score 10):

Even if wxWidgets is named here already:

wxWidgets!

Its a great and valuable Framwork (API, Class Library, whatever you may call it).

BUT: You can divide the functionality of this library into many small parts (base, core, gui, internet, xml) and use them, when necessary.

If you really want to make GOOD GUI applications, you have to use a GOOD API. wxWidgets is absolutly free (QT is not), only needs a small overhead in binary form, linked as dll or o-file is it about 2Megs, but has to offer all that you ever need to program great applications...

And wxWidgets is much more lighter than QT... and even better... :)

Try it...

Comment: How is Qt not "absolutely free"? I'm not knocking wxWidgets, but I don't think this is fair to Qt.

Comment: I'm guessing he's referring to the fact Qt is only free if you're willing to abide by its L/GPL licenses.  If you aren't, or can't, then you have to pony up for a commercial license.  wxWidgets is LGPL'd with a static linking exemption, meaning it's free to use regardless of the app's license as long as the source hasn't changed.

Answer (score 6):

[JUCE](http://www.juce.com/) is fairly light weight, it can be as simple as one .cpp & one .h file. (Look at amalgamated JUCE) It doesn't look like a standard windows app however. On the other hand, it is cross platform.

Comment: Cannot be freely used in commercial projects.

Answer (score 4):

[**CEGUI**](http://cegui.org.uk/) is a powerful GUI library but I am not sure (since you did not clarify) what you mean by lightweight. It contains a lot of headers, too, but they are all related to the GUI or the rendering of it. On my computer, the current Release built in default VS2010 Release mode takes about 3 MB in total for the dlls. There are of course assets that take space too, but clearly these may vary depending on your needs. It uses XML and image files in the assets, the images take the most space. It requires a bunch of dlls depending on your requirements (png, jpeg, xml parsing dlls) but they are all quite small in Release. So unless you are irrationally pedantic about having too many DLLs in use, this should be no issue.

It is written in C++ (0.7-1.0 will be based on C99 standard, 2.0+ will be in C++11 standard) and supports dynamic and static linking. Dynamic linking is the supported type on Windows. Static linking on Windows is not recommended for CEGUI.

Here a short summary of features:

- **Modern** (uses **STL**, **XML** for its asset files, and internally supports C99 standard for maximum compatibility, after the 1.0 Release it will be using C++11 in the development branch). It also has support for unicode characters and all sort of languages (as can be seen in the samples).
- Offers the following **widgets** out-of-the-box: text fields (scrollable), editboxes, multiline editboxes, spinners, checkboxes, buttons, radio-buttons, tabbed windows, progress bars, scrollable panes, sliders, dropdown-menus (comboboxes), menu bars, layout containers (vertical/horizontal) and more
- Published under the **Open Source MIT license**, one of the licenses offering you the most freedom, you will only need to distribute the license file with the application and that's it
- Layouts can easily be created and edited using a **WYSIWYG editor** written in Python. It is called CEED and is also freely available. It has gone through a lot of testing and is suitable to be used for production. A stable Release has been published and new features are in development for the future. An imageset editor is also available in the same application.
- As stated, this is **free for commercial use**. The only obligation you have is to distribute the license file.
- CEGUI is fit for **cross-platform** use. It officially supports **Windows, Linux, Mac OS**. It has also been used on iOS and Android. Android is supported in the development branch.

It was originally designed as a GUI library for games but it is also perfect for usage in scientific applications, rendering applications, visualisation. Desktop applications can be done as well. A simple Windows-like skin is available in the default assets.

It has been around for over 10 years, has an active community and is a robust, feature-rich and extensible library.

Answer (score 3):

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)

Comment: What's lightweight about wxWidgets???

Comment: hey, compared with Qt, everything is lightweight.

Comment: Ah, OK, I haven't looked at Qt yet. I found wxWidgets quite heavy.

Comment: Qt is a great library. I cannot imagine a better library out there. It has quirks (does not play nice with boost, for example), but it's well structured, documented and self-contained. If you use Qt, you don't generally need anything else. STL stuff, DB access, widgets, everything is in there.

Answer (score 2):

IUP is the smallest one i know, both in terms of learning curve, DLL size and features

Answer (score 0):

Try eGui (see [here](http://www.codeplex.com/egui) or [here](http://torjo.com/egui/)) or [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, WTL! WTL 9.0 was released on 2014-05-20

Answer (score 0):

try GTK with Glade3.

Answer (score 0):

## Microsoft Foundation Class Library (MFC)

Considering you are looking for a **WINDOWS ONLY SOLUTION**, (and that wxWidgets has been voted up on this thread) you may want to trade off some lightweight-ness and checkout MFC.
As far as **Windows is concerned**, MFC and wxWidgets seem to compete neck & neck, but overall, the former is lighter than the latter.

Some PROS:-

- MSVC MFC RAD support. Visual Studio arguably provides the best "RAD
  tool & GUI lib" combo. The only other "dynamic duo" that comes close
  is that of QtCreator & QT. wxSmith doesn't fully support all
- wxWidgets components, but it keeps improving. Very Very Rich set of
  commercial GUI components.
- Free (but proprietary).
- Very nice when it comes to databound controls.

Some CONS:-

- The day you decide to port to other platforms, you will wish you had gone with a cross platform lib.
- Proprietary nature of MFC means you will have to navigate licencing very very carefully. But AFAIK, MFC is free to redistribute in binary form.
  [Here's a nice article touching on the "oil and water" that is "MFC and FLOSS applications"](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winelib-guide/mfc-legal-issues). Apparently, they just might mix.

**Anyways, appart from MFC, I think the [FOX-Toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) also deserves a mention, but just like FLTK, the major downside is lack of decent IDEs and RAD tools as compared to, say, QT or wxWidgets**

Comment: It's a nightmare to work with MFC.

Comment: @the_drow did you read the full post before commenting (or downvoting)?

Comment: Yes I did. Feature set wise you might be right but MFC is simply unmaintainable and unreadable mess. I wouldn't recommend it to anyone for any reason?

Comment: Ignore the question mark please.

Comment: `MFC is simply unmaintainable and unreadable mess.`.....lol Really?

Comment: try RFC Framework https://github.com/hasaranga/RFC-Framework

Comment: If you're limiting yourself to windows I would go with WTL. That's as lightweight as it can get.