# gui library for beginner C++ programmer

Tags: c++, user-interface

which gui library would be good for cross platform for a beginner using C++

Comment: If you're a beginner do you want to worry about cross-platform?

Comment: I'd think it was a great time to worry about cross-platform! Before you get too familiar with MFC!

Comment: @Rup: Do you know any GUI library for C++ which is easier to use than Qt but is not cross-platform? I don't

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597182/windows-gui-c-programming

Comment: @Armen:  For beginners, MFC is far easier than Qt.  Qt doesn't surpass MFC in ease of use until you start doing more intermediate to advanced GUI work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283202/lightweight-c-gui-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762/linux-gui-development

Comment: @Armen:  I know, I know.  I hate to admit it, too.  But you have to give Microsoft some credit:  the wizards make basic UI's (which is what beginners would be doing) a cakewalk.  You actually have to understand some of the code to get Qt up and running.

Comment: @Zac: If you said that about .NET, I would totally agree. It's the best and easiest to use GUI library imho. But MFC... I mean, all those binding macros make me sick :)

Answer (score 10):

You should try out [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).
It's really nice and it has a lot of features, and it's cross platform.

And [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tutorials.html) is some tutorials for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875686/advice-for-c-gui-programming/875895#875895

Comment: Furthermore, there are many very good tutorials and docs for Qt.

Answer (score 2):

Qt.
It is cross platform, and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/). It is written in modern c++, uses stl, follows its conventions, includes support for utf-8. What's more, it's open source and cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/) that others have mentioned, take a look at [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/). It's cross platform and very usable for a beginner.